# How to handle cross section dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

SRC_RECORD (Records coming from src)

```
Str_id  Eff_From_Dt    Eff_to_dt    str_code    Action done of source table
12        01-Sep-13   01-Feb-14J         161    Reject it
12        01-Sep-13   31-Dec-13J         161    Insert
12        05-Jan-14   14-Jan-14J         161    Insert
```

Record Available in TGT_RECORD

```
Str_id  Eff_From_Dt    Eff_to_dt    str_code
12        08-Jul-13   31-Aug-13J         161
12        01-Jan-14   04-Jan-14J         161
12        15-Jan-14   30-Jan-14J         161
```

I created the above with a stored procedure, where I am checking date overlaps using

```
(@start_dt between effective_from_dt and effective_to_dt) OR
(@end_dt between effective_from_dt and effective_to_dt)
```

but I'm not getting the expected result. I want to reject the interval `(01-Sep-13, 01-Feb-14)` from `src`, because it overlaps with the existing available records in `tgt`.

Please help me, I am in trouble.

Comment: could you *please* reformat to question to make sense??

Comment: Can you show us the entire procedure/insert statement, rather than just (Part of) the `WHERE` clause? We also have no idea what `@start_dt` and `@end_dt` hold and how they are relevant to the rest of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're testing a time period to see if it overlaps with any existing time periods in your table.

Let's simplify for a moment, and look at a single check - call one time period s1-e1 and the second one s2-e2.

At the moment, in your `BETWEEN` statement, you're checking to see if s2 is between s1 and e1 OR e2 is between s1 and e1. You successfully catch the first three cases.

**Case 1**

```
        s1       e1
        |--------|   
s2        e2
|---------|
```

**Case 2**

```
     s1       e1
     |--------|
         s2        e2
         |---------|
```

**Case 3**

```
 s1                   e1
 |--------------------|
    s2           e2
    |------------|
```

However, there is one case you don't catch. Consider the possibility that the existing time period s1-e1 might fall completely within the time period you are testing. Neither s2 nor e2 are between s1 and e1, yet the time periods definitely overlap!

**Case 4**

```
        s1       e1
        |--------|
    s2                 e2
    |------------------|
```

You'll need to adjust your `WHERE` clause condition to check for the situation when `s2 < s1` AND `e2 > e1`

In your example, the range `01-Sep-13 -> 01-Feb-14` should be rejected because it contains both `01-Jan-14 -> 04-Jan-14` and `15-Jan-14 -> 30-Jan-14` within it. If you modify your query to check for case 4 above, then this overlap will also be rejected as required.

Comment: Yes i need to handle all above scenerio, which i am not able to do.

Comment: One way of doing it is to change your test clause to `(@start_dt between effective_from_dt and effective_to_dt) OR (@end_dt between effective_from_dt and effective_to_dt) OR ((@start_dt < effective_from_dt) AND (@end_dt > effective_to_dt))`. I _think_ @t-clausen.dk's check clause should also work...

Comment: People always seem to over-complicate overlap testing. Two periods overlap if period 1 starts before period 2 ends, and period 2 starts before period 1 ends. (I.e. the only test you need from your above examples is `s1<e2 and s2<e1`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliver Gosh, you're right! Still, I stand by my diagrams :) I was aiming to encourage thinking about the problem space rather than giving an exact where clause. Although I did anyway, in the end...But your solution is really succint. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using sqlserver 2000, here is a solution that works for that. It only selects the 'good' rows

```
declare @TGT_RECORD table (Str_id INT, Effective_From_Dt DATE, Effective_to_dt DATE, str_code INT)
insert @TGT_RECORD values
(12,        '08-Jul-13','31-Aug-13',   161),
(12,        '01-Jan-14','04-Jan-14',   161),
(12,        '15-Jan-14','30-Jan-14',   161)

declare @SRC_RECORD table (Str_id INT, Effective_From_Dt DATE, Effective_to_dt DATE, str_code INT)
insert @SRC_RECORD values
(12,        '01-Sep-13','01-Feb-14',161),
(12,        '01-Sep-13','31-Dec-13',161),
(12,        '05-Jan-14','14-Jan-14',161)

select t1.Str_id, t1.Effective_From_Dt Eff_from_Dt, t1.Effective_to_dt Eff_to_Dt, t1.str_code--, case when a.chk is not null then 'Reject' else 'Insert' end Action
from @SRC_RECORD t1
where not exists 
(
select 1 from 
@TGT_RECORD t2
where 
t1.Effective_From_Dt between t2.Effective_From_Dt and t2.Effective_to_dt
or t1.Effective_to_Dt between t2.Effective_From_Dt and t2.Effective_to_dt
or t2.Effective_From_Dt between t1.Effective_From_Dt and t1.Effective_to_dt
)
```